# TextView position XY of a string

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I've got a `LinearLayout` with many `TextViews` as a scrollable list.

Now I want to position an `ImageView` next to some words in the `TextView`. I only know the index of the position in the text.

Where can I calculate the x/y-position of this position?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use relativelayout instead and in the layout add layout_aliegnLeft="+id/the id of the text view" to the imageview

Comment: The `TextView` can contain more than one line (eg. 30 lines) and I want to overlay the image in line 12 or 25. That's why your hint doesn't work.